# Can't assign this in constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, assign

I'm trying to merge the props from `values` into `this`.

The following throws an error. How can I do this?

```
this = {...this, ...values}
```

Comment: I think that's trying to create a new object and assign it to `this`, not merging properties into `this`.

Comment: `this` is a reserved javascript word and cannot be overwrote, have you tried using a different var name?

Comment: `this` is unassignable. what are you **really** trying to do?

Comment: I think he's trying to do the equivalent of jQuery's`$.extend(this, values)`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could extend `this` with [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method:

```
class Foo {
  constructor (props) {
    Object.assign(this, props);
  }
}

const foo = new Foo({ a: 1 });
console.log(foo.a); // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your use of the spread operator, it looks like you're using a Stage 3 proposal for ECMAScript.

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread

Try the Object.assign method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

> Object.assign(*target*, *...sources*);

Comment: What is the purpose of ECMA making this so awkward? Is this considered bad practice?