# Invalid left-hand side in assignment in constructor

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

If I'm trying to make a player, I could do it like this

```
let player = game.add.sprite(100, 100, 'player');
player.speed = 4;
player.gravity = 1;
```

I could turn this into a constructor function like this

```
let player = new Player(100, 100);

function Player(x, y) {
  this = game.add.sprite(x, y, 'player');
  this.speed = 4;
  this.gravity = 1;
}
```

assigning this.speed and this.gravity work fine, but assigning this returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Comment: Try something like " this.sprite = game.add.sprite(x, y, 'player');".

Comment: You cannot assign a value to `this`.

Comment: Use `this.sprite = game.add.sprite(x, y, 'player');`. You cannot modify / assign to `this`. Eventually your `Player` could extend the Phaser's Sprite prototype like i.e: `class Player extends Phaser.Sprite {`

Comment: Is your intent that a `Player` *has a* "sprite" or that it *is a* "sprite"?

Comment: If the `Player` is the sprite, it's probably better to make a function that returns a new sprite, not a constructor that returns a `Player` object that is a sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** want, to do this you could do something like this

```
function Player(x, y) {
  let p =  game.add.sprite(x, y, 'player');
  p.speed = 4;
  return p;
}

let player = new Player(100, 100);
```

**BUT** two questions, why do you want to do this? and which phaser Version are you using? There might be better solutions, like inheritance / extending.

**For Phaser CE / 2:** checkout [this example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/text/extending-text) offical example
**For Phaser 3:** checkout [this example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/physics/arcade/extending-arcade-sprite) offical example

> *You would have to adapt the examples to your specific case, but they show how it can work*

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.assign` to assign value directly to `this` in a constructor:

```
function Player(x, y) {
  Object.assign(this,game.add.sprite(x, y, 'player'));
  this.speed = 4;
  this.gravity = 1;
}
```

Sauce: [Can't assign this in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897533/cant-assign-this-in-constructor)